# Imagesharp.Web Custom URL Pattern

Tags: .net-5, asp.net-core-middleware, imagesharp

I'm trying to map existing URL pattern to imagesharp.web to resize images.

I found a method to do that using URL rewrites. Other than that, Is there any standard way to map an existing URL pattern to an imagesharp.web URL pattern?

Existing URL Pattern:

```
https://{myDomain}/process_resize_{width}x{height}/{folder}/{filename.extension}
```

URL accepted by Imagesharp.Web:

```
https://localhost:44397/5dd74c00631a76.86137975.jpeg?width=415&height=415&quality=30&rmode=max
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can implement your own version of [`IRequestParser`](https://docs.sixlabors.com/api/ImageSharp.Web/SixLabors.ImageSharp.Web.Commands.IRequestParser.html) and use whatever URL pattern you want.